# Multiple Identity Provider Login OAuth/Open ID

Tags: android, oauth, asp.net-identity, openid, identityserver4

There are mobile applications such as games where they allow the user to register and log in using Google, Facebook, or their own server. After logging in using third party provider, they seem to be able to store user information such as game progress to their server so it means that they can associate third party accounts to their user profile database. How do people typically do this?

I am using Identity Server as my main Identity Provider. It uses ASP.NET Identity to manage users. I have an android application which uses resource owner grant to get authorization token from the Identity Server. A new user can register a new account by going to the site where identity server is hosted.

Now I want to add a button to login via Google or Facebook within my Android Application. When a user logs in via Google or Facebook, the user information should be retrieved and then a registration form within the Android app will show with fields automatically filled up based on user information from third party providers. User can then register using that detail and save the user to the Identity Server with an identifier that that is a Google or Facebook account. Just like an asp.net identity site does it but for mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can have a button that allows user to Log in using third party Identity server such as Facebook, Google. The only thing I am wondering is I am not sure if you will be able to make them register using those username and password.

The flow you can think of is:

- Give the user an option of logging in as Facebook, Google etc.
- User will get redirected to the login page for those third party services.
- When they log in you will receive a token from Facebook that will have claims for the user and then you can do claims transformation and assign the token to your user.
- Using the same token you can have the data stored in your database related to the user.
- So in your database you will have 2 tokens, 1 from the Facebook and the other one that you will have for your own app.
- The only option we can give is log in using Facebook. But by maintaining the information that the Identity server provides you can register the user on the back end directly so user don't have to register by himself.

Answer (score 1):

Resource owner grant is a dead end here. You need to switch to a logon workflow using a browser. This will give you the external logins for "free".

https://vimeo.com/171942749

This is also encouraged for security reasons - see the spec I link to from the presentation.

Comment: I am using a trusted application and would like to emulate apps with their own personalized login native UI. Web view would be my last resort though.